# how to scrap data from <script nonce> this type of tags with scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I want to scrap latitude longitude values from a website "https://pfchangsmexico.com.mx/ubicaciones/" of every restaurants those values are present at xpath= /html/body/script[1]. provide me code with scrapy how scrap those values from this

```
import json
from scrapy import Selector
import scrapy
import re


class TrySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "try"
    allowed_domains = ["pfchangsmexico.com.mx"]
    start_urls = ["https://pfchangsmexico.com.mx/index.html"]

    def parse(self, response):
        location_page = response.css('div a::attr(href)').get()
        yield scrapy.Request(url=location_page, callback=self.parse_info)

    def parse_info(self, response):
        restaurant_names = []
        for location in response.css('div.wpb_wrapper p span::text').getall():
            match = re.search(r'(P\.F\. Chang\’s)(.*)', location)
            if match:
                restaurant_names.append(match.group(1) + match.group(2))

        print(restaurant_names)
        print(len(restaurant_names))

        addresses = response.xpath('//div/p/span[2]').getall()

        addresses = [address for address in addresses if address !=
                     '<span style="font-family: Avenir;">Servicio a domicilio:</span>']
        addresses = [address.replace('</span>', '') for address in addresses]
        addresses = [re.sub(r'<.*?>', '', address) for address in addresses]

        print(addresses)
        print(len(addresses))

        sel = Selector(response=response)

        # Extract the content of the <script nonce> element
        script_content = sel.xpath(
            '//html/body/script[1][contains(text(), "onEmbedLoad")]/text()').get()

        # Extract the latitude and longitude values
        latitude = sel.re_first(r'latitude":(\d+\.\d+)')
        longitude = sel.re_first(r'longitude":(-\d+\.\d+)')

        if latitude and longitude:
            print("Latitude:", latitude)
            print("Longitude:", longitude)
        else:
            print("Latitude and longitude not found.")

        yield {
            'name': restaurant_names,
            'address': addresses
        }
# /html/body/script[1]
```

this is the code I have tried but with this I am unable to scrap latitude and longitude from the give wesbite other data is scraped properly provide me proper code to scrap latitude and longitude of every restaurant
website = https://pfchangsmexico.com.mx/ubicaciones/

Answer (score 0):

There are no text matching `r'latitude":(\d+\.\d+)`. Beside `xpath('//html/body/script[1][contains(text(),"onEmbedLoad")]/text()')` points to `iframe`. So I doubt that you can access it directly. You might have to use `scrapy-selenium` `driver.switch_to.frame(frameElement)`.
After that you can do something like this.

```
place_name = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div.place-name').get_attribute('innerText')
script_content = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//html/body/script[1][contains(text(), "onEmbedLoad")]/text()').get_attribute('innerText')

# match for 'P. F. Chang's Plaza Carso, C. Lago Zurich 245, Amp Granada, Miguel Hidalgo, 11520 Ciudad de México, CDMX",[19.441211,-99.204493],'
location = re.findall(f"{place_name}[^[]*(\[[\d.,-]+\])", script_content)[0]

print(location) # String [19.441211,-99.204493]
```

Comment: with this lines of code i will be able to lat lon values?

Comment: I haven't tested it yet. But it *should* give you the result I mentioned. I used regex101.com to get the regex. You can try that as well.